# How to show div when classes are added dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I am working with Swiper.js slider.

When slide is **active** I want to add two **divs** below slide as description.

**index.html**

```
 <div class="swiper-container about">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide about one">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img src="one.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="employee">
        <h3>Tom<br><span>Founder</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="employee-details-text">
        Description
      </div>

      <div class="employee-details-note">
        Description 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide about two">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img src="two.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="employee">
        <h3>Ine<br><span>Founder and CEO</span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="employee-details-text">
        Description
      </div>

      <div class="employee-details-note">
        Description 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When slide is active class `swiper-slide-active` is added

```
<div class="swiper-slide about one swiper-slide-active">
```

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if($("div.swiper-slide.one").hasClass('swiper-slide-active')){
    $("employee-details-text, employee-details-note").show();
  }else{
    $("employee-details-text, employee-details-note").hide();
  }
});
```

I added `one` and `two` class to `swiper-slide` div so I can resolve slides.

With code that I have `employee-details-note` div is being showed all the time and `employee-details-text` is not being showed at all no meter if slide has class `swiper-slide-active` or not.

Comment: `$("employee-details-text")` looks for the tag `<employee-details-text>` (which doesn't exist). you're looking for a class name, so use: '$(".employee-details-text")`

Comment: Why do not you implement it with CSS?

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Changed it it was silly mistake but now none of divs are shown

Comment: `is('swiper-slide-active')` = `<swiper-slide-active>`.

Comment: I agree with Ernesto.  This should be done with CSS, not javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to use JS for what you want to do, here is a CSS code that can help you.

---

```
.swiper-slide .employee-details-text, .swiper-slide .employee-details-note{
    display:none;
    }
    .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .employee-details-text, .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .employee-details-note{
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Or if you used `.swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active)` you could have a single rule.

Comment: Thank you! Yes this works fine :) But why is it better to use CSS over jQuery just as for simplicity or?

Comment: The reason is because CSS already fills this need.  There is no reason to add logic that toggles inline styles when the CSS stylesheets are automatically re-evaluated when ever the page redraws. @user9347049

Comment: I agree 100% with @Taplar.